# #define _AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT causes a stream of compilation errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have an MFC C++ project compiler under Visual Studio 2008.

I'm adding a _AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT in my stdafx.h before the #include  to avoid all the debug new and deletes that MFC provides (I wish to provide my own for better cross platform compatibility).

However when I do this I get a stream of errors such as the following:

```
>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2059: syntax error : '__asm'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ','
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(62) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1
```

I "think" it may have something to do with an __asm int 3 call but I cannot be sure.  Has anyone had this problem before?  If so, how did you fix it?  Am i stuck with MFC's memory tracking?  I really hope not because it will make my libraries a lot less cross platform :(

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with one method which involves using the /FORCE:MULTIPLE command line to force it to use mine instead of the MFC one.  It all seems to be working quite nicely.  I can, now, even track "mallocs" and "new"s performed by functions not owned by me :)

If anyone has any better solutions then please post them but for now this seems to solve my problem :)

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question of why your "cross-platform" library is linking MFC?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you fixed your compilation issue?

I'm getting exactly the same compile errors as you - did you remove your #define _AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT?

Comment: i DID remove my define and seeing as all the problems related to that new definition of new the force multiple fixed the problem. Fat Elvis's post explains why such a define is bad (tm).

Answer (score 2):

I tried messing with the `_AFX_NO_DAO_SUPPORT` macro in the past and all it did was lead to endless crashes. I eventually came across this article:

[PRB: Problems Occur When Defining `_AFX_NO_XXX`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140751)

It doesn't specifically list the one you are attempting to use, but it may still apply.

Comment: Cool definitely worth knowing but the define im trying to use does not appear to affect VTABLES.  It appears to only be for a bunch of service functions rather than used in classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the #define in your project compile options rather than at the top of stdafx.h.

How can you expect to build a cross-platform library if you're using MFC? Avoiding the new and delete overloads won't make a difference.

Moreover, you'll never write allocation trackers as reliable and complete as those provided by MFC. [YAGNI](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html), focus on developing your actual application.

Comment: My libraries are cross platform not the MFC portion.

Comment: Also worth noting that putting it into the project defines does not work either.

Comment: If your library is cross-platform why does it need an MFC #define?