# Trying to reduce size of memory allocations in debug compilations for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, crt

I have a software that is compiled in debug mode for ease of support (getting dump files, etc.). Visual studio version is 2008.

We have noticed that our memory allocations suffer a huge overhead as a result. Every memory allocation (even of a single pointer) done when DEBUG is defined takes with it a big header identifying the allocating file, line, etc.

We are trying to stay in DEBUG and yet reduce the overhead. It seems that defining _AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT should do the trick - but defining it on the project level or in our stdafx.h file leads to a long list of compilation errors:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(66) : error C2059: syntax error : '__asm'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtls_.h(66) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
....

The error is the same is reported under : [#define _AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT causes a stream of compilation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265574/define-afx-no-debug-crt-causes-a-stream-of-compilation-errors), but the requirement to create your own new is not relevant here and I found no solution there.

Another alternative I saw in posts is playing with _CrtSetDbgFlag - but that seems just to avoid writing the information to the heap - but still allocates the memory for it - that's not what we are looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [#define \_AFX\_NO\_DEBUG\_CRT causes a stream of compilation errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265574/define-afx-no-debug-crt-causes-a-stream-of-compilation-errors)

Comment: by the way, I don't understand why can't you use release build instead. Enable PDB generation (Generate debug info option) in project settings. Don't distribute PDB file.

Comment: You then don't need to worry about overheard due to memory allocation, everything is optimized well in release build

Comment: Thank you for the prompts. 

As for the other post - yes, it's the same problem, but I don't have the limitation of trying to provide my own new and delete, just want to avoid the overhead of the CRT block - so I was hoping maybe somebody can help me (none of the answers there provided a solution).

As for moving to release - it's a huge change that we are trying to avoid (as it will change many behaviors) and make it more difficult to debug. Good to know of the PDB generation option.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
```

From MSDN, The #define statement maps the base versions of the CRT heap functions to the corresponding debug versions. By including crtdbg.h, you map the malloc and free functions to their debug versions, _malloc_dbg and _free_dbg, which keep track of memory allocation and deallocation. This is what you want to avoid.
This mapping occurs only in a debug build (in which _DEBUG is defined). Release builds use the ordinary malloc and free functions.

To serve your purpose, 
just `#undef _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC`.

Go to Visual Studio project settings - > Debug settings, go to C/C++ Preprocessor settings, Add `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` macro under "Undefine Preprocessor Definitions" settings.

You should be able to generate a DEBUG executable which will not generate overheard during memory allocations at runtime.

Comment: I tried this (the definition I found was under advanced) - but I see no change in memory allocation size or in the function as I debug into. I still end up inside:

void* __cdecl operator new(size_t nSize, int nType, LPCSTR lpszFileName, int nLine)

Comment: @RamiJaschek I guess the key is undefining the thing early enough and being sure it is not defined afterwards - your best bet is looking at preprocessed files.

Comment: Is there any way to get this done earlier then defining it at the project level? I tried adding this also in my Stdafx.h file - to no avail. Basically I am testing this with a very simple visual studio generated file where I only added a simple main allocating a bunch of objects. The object I am allocating is just a few bytes and yet I spend about 70 bytes per allocation. It's a very simple, minimal project.

Comment: @RamiJaschek I'm not sure how to do this the earliest but when I needed something like this I made it one of the first lines inside `stdafx.h`. It's entirely possible that the symbol is defined later in some other headers you include. Looking at preprocessed files could help localize the problem.